# Job Rescheduling is not working

Tags: c#, quartz.net, job-scheduling

I would like to change the trigger of one of my jobs. So what I am doing is to first see if my job has any triggers associated with it. If so I `Reschedule` with a new trigger that the user has chosen. But when I look at my `AdoJobStore` the new trigger is not there and the job will stop running after rescheduling.

I have put this entire code in a `try-catch` block, but I am not receiving any `Exception`s, but that is maybe because I should catch `JobExecutionException`s instead of just `Exception`s?

```
var jobKey = new JobKey(jobName, jobGroup);
IScheduler sched = scheduler.GetScheduler();
IList<ITrigger> triggers = sched.GetTriggersOfJob(jobKey);
if (triggers.Count != 0)
{
    ITrigger existingTrigger = triggers[0];
    sched.UnscheduleJob(existingTrigger.Key);
    ITrigger newTrigger = BuildTrigger(triggerName, triggerGroup);
    IJobDetail job = sched.GetJobDetail(jobKey);
    DialogResult dr = MsgBox.Show(string.Format("Confirm campaign '{0}' with the schedule '{1}'?", lblCampaignName.Text, txtbxMessage.Text), "Confirm Schedule", MsgBox.Buttons.YesNo, MsgBox.Icon.Question);
    if (dr == DialogResult.Yes)
    {

        sched.RescheduleJob(existingTrigger.Key, newTrigger);
        int updateResult = UpdateCampaignSchedule();
        if (updateResult == 1)
            MsgBox.Show("Campaign schedule successfully updated!", "Edit schedule", MsgBox.Buttons.OK, MsgBox.Icon.Info);
        else
            MsgBox.Show("Unable to update campaign schedule in the database.", "Edit schedule", MsgBox.Buttons.OK, MsgBox.Icon.Error);
    }
}
else
{
..
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of calling `sched.UnscheduleJob(existingTrigger.Key`. This deletes the trigger from the job store. So, when calling `sched.RescheduleJob(existingTrigger.Key, newTrigger)` quartz cannot find the old trigger to replace it with the new one (if you look at the return value it will be null) nor will it throw an exception unless your new trigger is invalid.

Remove `sched.UnscheduleJob(existingTrigger.Key, newTrigger` and it should work.